# Mapping TypeScript types from Object => Object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, tsc

Say I have an object like so:

```
export const v = {
   a() : Promise<X>{

   },
   b() : Promise<Y>{

   },
   c() : Promise<Z>{

   }
}
```

my question is - is there any way to get the type of v, but map the type, so that it looks something like this:

```
export type V = {
  a: X, 
  b: Y,
  c: Z
}
```

basically I am mapping each key in the object, to the resolved value of the respective promise.

Basically, I am trying to derive a modified type, from something that's declared statically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using conditional types and mapped type:

```
class X{}
class Y{}
class Z{}
export const v = {
    a() : Promise<X>{
        return null as any;
    },
    b() : Promise<Y>{
        return null as any;
    },
    c() : Promise<Z>{
        return null as any;
    },
}

type ExtractAllPromisses<T> = 
{ 
    // Take all keys of T ([P in keyof T])
    // and if the property P of T is a promise returning function (T[P] extends ()=> Promise<infer U>)
    // then the new type of P will be the return type of the promise (saved in U)
    // Otherwise the new type of P is never
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends ()=> Promise<infer U> ? U : never 
};

export type V = ExtractAllPromisses<typeof v> // same as type V = { a: X; b: Y; c: Z; }
```

There are variations you can do in the conditional type depending on your need, the example above works specifically for a type which has just functions that take no arguments and return a `Promise`

If you want to match a function with any number of arguments you can use:

```
type ExtractAllPromisses<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...args: any[])=> Promise<infer U> ? U : never };
```

If your type also has properties that are not promise returning functions and you want to preserve those properties (ie `v` also has a field `foo:number`) you can use:

```
type ExtractAllPromisses<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...args: any[])=> Promise<infer U> ? U : T[P] };
```

If you want to exclude properties that are not a promise retuning function. You can filter the keys:

```
type PromiseFunctionFields<T> = { [P in keyof T] : T[P] extends (...args: any[])=> Promise<any> ? P : never}[keyof T];
type ExtractAllPromisses<T> = { [P in PromiseFunctionFields<T>]: T[P] extends (...args: any[])=> Promise<infer U> ? U : T[P] };
```